# How to scale image to column width without changing ratio in CSS (Bootstrap 4)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have thumbnails with 200px height. I would like to scale my thumbnail image to the full width of a column (Bootstrap 4) without changing the ratio of the image. The part of the image that doesn't fit the column height should just be hidden. How can I do this?

**HTML**

```
<a class="b" href="#">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <img class="b__thumbnail" src="img/placeholders/b_thumbnail.jpg" %}">
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="b__category" style="color: blue;">Bla</span>
        <h3 class="b_title">Bla</h3>
        <p class="b__text">Bla</p>
        <span class="b__meta">Bla</span>
    </div>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.b__thumbnail {
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I am guessing width:auto; but a demo would be helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add **`overflow:hidden`** to your parent div and **`height: auto`** to your image like this:

```
.mb-3 {
    height: 200px; /* You can remove this if you have already specified the 200px height of thumbnails somewhere else */
    overflow:hidden;
}

.b__thumbnail {
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

---

**jsFiddle with dummy image:** https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/oy5xaf5g/

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. I was putting `overflow:hidden` in `b__thumbnail` class haha

Comment: haha glad I could help man. Do mark this as the correct answer if it helped you solve your issue. Cheers mate!

Comment: I celebrated too early. The thumbnail in the middle didn't scale to the 200px height. Any idea why? https://i.imgur.com/8HyLTux.png

Comment: Can you post a screenshot with an arrow off where the height didn't scale. Can't amke out what you mean from the current screenshot.

Comment: Oh you're talking about the calendar column? You want it to have a height equal to 200px too or?

Comment: Yes it should be 200px height, without stretching it. All thumbnails should have 100% column width and 200px height without affecting their aspect ratio.

Comment: But that would mean the calendar width might get chopped up if it exceeds a certain amount.

Comment: CAn you please provide the html, css, js of the calendar too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170967/discussion-between-dunkubok-and-andrewl).

Comment: Oh ok. So the calendar is another image on its own `mb-3` div? If so, then just replicate the code above and replace `b__thumbnail` with the class name of the calendar div.

Comment: hmmmm. Can you please replicate the above image in a jsfiddle and I'll check it out.

Comment: Using `object-fit: cover;` solved my problem. Thanks!